# Systematically change folder icons in Windows 7 to accommodate Movie Collection

Tags: windows-7, icons

I was google-ing for the past day or so, and could not find an easier way of changing the icons for a folder in Windows 7 than the following... The thing is, I have a movie x264 collection, and each movie is stored in its own folder. I would like to change the folder icon for the specific movie with the use of an .ico file.

I'm totally able to do so. I use [Axialis IconWorkshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop) to convert my Movie Posters from JPG to ICO, 256x256. Then I go manually in Windows, right-click on the folder, Properties. Click on Customize, Change Icon, browse, select the newly created icon, Apply, OK, and voila, Bob's your Uncle.

The problem I have is, Windows creates a hidden desktop.ini file inside the folder, which describes location of the ico file. This path is 'hardcoded' if I can call it that. So, whenever I copy/rename this folder to another location, the icon dissapears, and one has to Customize, Browse, Select, and Apply again.

```
desktop.ini

[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=H:\Riaan\HD Movies\The Bourne Ultimatum - 1080p\bourne_ultimatum.ico,0
```

Is there no other way of doing this?

- I'm using Media Player Classic with GPU support to playback my 1080p/720p movies, as Windows Media Player and VLC cannot do this...

See this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a relative path like this. Better late than never! Hope this helps other users

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=name_of_ico_file.ico,0
```